# What is this insect

Tags: species-identification, species, hemiptera

[image]
This was found in my house in florida

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your question seems fine, but could you add the size of the animal (and maybe give a somewhat more precise title to your question - e.g. What is this x cm winged insect found in Florida, US?), please? That makes it more likely for you to get an answer.

Answer (score 2):

That is a Milkweed Assasin Bug, *Zelus longipes*. Order Hemiptera, family Reduviidae. Here is a good website that describes a lot about them. http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/beneficial/bugs/zelus_longipes.htm